# Statistics question about particle hitting a detector and chance of detection

Tags: statistics, physics, problem-solving, poisson-distribution

This is a statistics problem which i need some help with as amu unsure how to answer it.

*Particles  hitting  a  detector  undergo  a  collision  after  an  average  path  length Lo=  10  cm.   After  the  collision,  the  particle  deposits  all  of  its  energy  in  thedetector and is stopped.  How thick does the detector need to be so that 99%of the incoming particles are stopped?*

I believe that using a poisson distribution may help but tried using the poisson distribution and couldn't get a reasonable answer.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simple model of the situation that I'm sure you're using, the path length will not be Poisson-distributed, but rather exponentially distributed (it is the interevent time of a Poisson process, not the number of events). So you want to compute the 99th percentile of the exponential distribution with mean $10.$ Recall that if $X$ has that distribution, we have $$ P(X\ge x) = e^{-x/10},$$ so just set $0.01 = e^{-x/10}$ and solve.